# Hide master branch in GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, github-desktop

Our implementation of GitHub is very basic.
We have one master branch (default) and then one open branch (DEV) for new developments.
Ideally we won't have more than one branch open at the same time.

Master branch is a protected branch so only admin can do changes on there.

The idea is to use GitHub Desktop to manage the developments locally in a computer as it would be too complex to manage it via the WebUI due to the kind of files being used.
Also we have the challenge that team is mostly consultant/external and rotating, so not everyone is familiar with the GitHub funcitonality...

Due to this, I would like to know if it is possible to avoid checking out the master branch when cloning our repository.

I am mainly aiming for this approach as I have problems when someone clones the repository locally and starts developing into the local master branch (without switching to the DEV branch first) and getting the error when pushing to server (due to the protected  branch).
At that point the developer has already developed a lot and  now is  time for him to switch all his development to the proper branch instead of using the master one...

Is there any way to achieve that initial checkout from master to be avoided?

**EDIT:** 
just  immediately after posting I thought on changing the default branch to DEV so when  someone clones it will always be directly targeted to the DEV branch instead of master...

Would this have any bad consequence for such a simple implementation?

Note that branch is created by admin as well as deleting it after pull request has been merged...
So this could be his responsibility to change the default branch every time a new development needs to be done and  move it back to the master when development is  finished...

Does it have sense?

Comment: You can set the default branch to something else, then that branch will be the one that is checked out by default when a repository is cloned.

Comment: I was too slow :) I indeed think that would be the best way. Hopefullly no impact on it nor bad prractice?

Comment: I don't see any bad consequences, but then I wouldn't be doing that kind of development either, I would force pull requests against dev as well, considering dev as "next set of features to release [to master]".

Comment: If the developers get into the habit of always starting their own branch, tied to the issue/feature they're working on, and have to always use a PR to get it into dev, they would soon stop doing the wrong thing by default, because "by default" has changed.

Comment: Sorry I dont fully understand what you mean with: "I would force pull requests against dev as well".  It is important to see that in this approach we wont have more than one DEV branch open at the same time and is always one branch/one developer (basic process as we are managing very small repositories but a lot of them -> simple plugin/module developent). Would your comment apply in this approach as well?

Comment: And developer wont (they shouldnt) create branches but only the admin. :)

Comment: I'm not used to having many repositories, so then my opinion on that is probably not useful to you :) We work on one major project so we create many branches in that instead, according to open and in-progress issues, and then merge those into our main branch and then delete the temporary feature branches. That merge process is always using a PR. But that doesn't make much sense if you open a new repository for new features/plugins.

Comment: Well every repository is a complete independent application (one is one report while the other is a set of files that define a new EDI integration). So there is never anything in common between them. Just did some tests and looks like it would fit great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a repository, whatever is "checked out" on the remote end becomes the default branch that is checked out on the local end.

For remote bare repositories, which is usually the norm, you have a "default branch" configuration that is used. In your case this is set to master.

You can change this on github to be DEV instead, so that fresh clones of the repository checks out DEV by default instead of master.

You do this by navigating to your repository on github, and click on the "X branches" button that is just to the right of the button/dropdown that shows the default branch selection on your repository page:

[image: branch selection on github]

on the page that shows branches, click on the "Change default branch" button to the right of your current default branch:

[image: Change default branch button]

and then finally select your new default branch and click Update:

[image: Updating default branch on github]